# Set size for Input item using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is the following code:

```
$(".translated").mouseenter(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("editable")){
        return;
    }
    var h=$(this).height();
    var w=$(this).width();
    $(this).empty();
    $("<input/>", {
        type: "text",
        height:h,
        width:w,
        value:$(this).text()
        }).appendTo(this);
    $(this).height(h);
    $(this).width(w);
    $(this).addClass("editable");
});
```

This code removes text from a `<div>` container and inserts an `<input>` item into it. But there is the problem: the new `<input>` item has height larger than the `<div>` container despite the values of the `h` and `w`. How can I fix it?

Comment: You should take into account the border and the margin (depending of your css) of `input` and `div`. You can also use `jQuery.fn.outerHeight` (see http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/).

Comment: Bear in mind the CSS box model: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Comment: Using `.outerHeight()` may be worse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate how much extra space is taken up by the border and padding of the `<input>` element and then subtract that from the height of the container `<div>`. This will give you the actual height that you need to set the `<input>` element:

```
var h = $(this).height(); // The height of the container <div>
//...
var $newInput = $("<input/>", { type: "text", value:$(this).text()}).appendTo(this);
var fullHeight = newElem.outerHeight();
var innerHeight = newElem.height();
var paddingEtc = fullHeight - innerHeight;
$newInput.height(h - paddingEtc);
```

You'll probably have to follow the same method to set the width of the `<input>` as well.

You can see it working here (height only at the moment): http://jsfiddle.net/XrGxx/